# lightning:openFiles in classic

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, lightning-out

I've my list of files in a Lightning component, and I'm using - lightning:openFiles (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_lightning_openFiles.htm) to view the file in Preview mode. Everything works fine in Lightning environment.

When I load the same component in Visualforce page (using lightning out) it fails with the below error:

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed: cs:IL_File$controller$openFiles [undefined is not an object (evaluating '$A.get('e.lightning:openFiles').fire')] Failing descriptor: {cs:IL_File$controller$openFiles}
```

In the above link it says "the event opens the SVG file preview player" ... I think it is a component not available in the VF Page. If we append that component in VF it might work, hope I'm right.

Can you of suggest me a way to get lightning:openFiles work in LightningOut?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible

Also - the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_lightning_openFiles.htm) states exactly where this component is available:

> This event is supported in Lightning Experience, the Salesforce1 mobile browser app, and Lightning communities. It isn’t supported in the deprecated Koa and Kokua community templates.

This means that it is not supported in any classic Salesforce UI

Comment: Thanks. As they have not mentioned anything about Classic ... I thought may be.

Comment: Yes this is a bit confusing, but this statement is the actual list of environments that this technology is supported, if you are not in this list - you are not supported

Comment: Any thoughts on how to make this working in Classic, thanks.